# Displaying multiple combobox in excel using macro

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I want to display about 100 combo boxes in my rows in excel.

How can I write a macro code using loop iteration instead writing it one by one like this:

```
with combobox1
   .additem("stuff 1")
   .additem("stuff 2")
end with

with combobox2
   .additem("stuff 1")
   .additem("stuff 2")
end with
.
..
with combobox100
   .additem("stuff 1")
   .additem("stuff 2")
end with
```

I know it doesn't effective way. How to write the looping??? I try this but doesn't work.

```
for i = 1 to 100
   with combobox & i
       .additem("stuff 1")
       .additem("stuff 2")
   end with
next i
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are ActiveX ComboBoxes you can do it like this:

```
For Each s In OLEObjects
 If s.OLEType = 2 And s.progID = "Forms.ComboBox.1" Then
  ' do your stuff
  s.Object.AddItem ("Stuff 1")
 End If
Next
```

Or to access your ComboBox using the Shapes collection:

```
For Each s In Shapes
 If s.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
  If s.OLEFormat.progID = "Forms.ComboBox.1" Then
   s.OLEFormat.Object.Object.AddItem ("Stuff 1")
  End If
 End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you. It work. Next I just need to learn OLEObjects..
thank